# tr.style.display = 'none' leaves annoying space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript function that strips out some table rows. I just want to hide them because i want to show them later again.

I use **style.display=none** which seems to work.

```
tr.style.display = 'none';
```

When I want to show them again I just call :

```
tr.style.display = '';
```

And my table row is displayed again. Works fine.

However in Internet Explorer, there is an annoying blank space about 1-2pixel high where the row used to be. Chrome hides this row completely.

(I can't show in JSFiddle because IE does not work in jsfiddle).

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Which version of IE? JSFiddle works fine on IE9 onwards.

Comment: unfortunately 8. No way around it.

Comment: is there any default padding on the row in IE ? maybe if you reset it you'll have no more blank space (you can have a look with the IE developer tools and inspect your row)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of how it looks in IE?

Comment: if you are using javascript to output the rows why not just flag them and skip printing the row on interation instead of using CSS? this way there'll be no DOM element at all. Can you post a fiddle anyway, show html, js and your CSS..

Comment: maybe you need apply a reset on an element like tr or table..., have look at http://www.cssreset.com/ (because each browser adds default style to elements and maybe it causes blank space)

Comment: i just had another look. hiding a row leaves exactly a white row of one pixel in height.

Answer (score 1):

Lol you're going to kick yourself, just tested this out on IE8, and i was getting the same and couldn't figure out why, then i remembered old school html.. Add this to your table.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

I was getting the 1px space too, adding that and then gone.  Also, try using * in your stylesheet to drop padding and margin. Then add classes to control your table. Here is the code I tested with.

```
<html><head><title></title>
    <style>
        * { padding:0; margin:0; }
        .visiblerow { background:#ccc; }
        .visiblecell { padding: 10px; margin: 10px; }
        .hiddenrow { background:#000; display: none; }
        .hiddencell { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr class="visiblerow">
            <td class="visiblecell">test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hiddenrow">
            <td class="hiddencell">hide me</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="visiblerow">
            <td class="visiblecell">test</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove the cellpadding, spacing, border from the table tags in IE8 and you'll see the 1px space return. Now also with classes defined you can create a nice javascript function that can toggle the classes on the rows as well.

Comment: great. however i cant set spacing and padding to zero, because the table grid needs to be respected.

Comment: add spacing and padding to the styles for your rows that aren't hidden, use a class perhaps..  hiddenrow & visiblerow class.  Visible row class can have CSS padding attributes added to it. Editing my answer to better show this.

Comment: tried everything, nothing seems to work. We have had to change the logic to the server side.

Comment: I'd like to see the full code, there is no way this shouldn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/7cRs8/ - jsfiddle explodes in IE8 but, you can still load that example in quirks mode..  added final update to code in answer